# Why is my list returning in ascending numerical order?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to assign an integer to a corresponding letter character using the alphabet with a space included.  After I create a list of the letters I run loops to assign an integer.  When I try to print the list it is in ascending order when I want it to be ordered by the corresponding value of the letters.  I also noticed it is not returning enough indices in the num_sample_list.

```
abc=['','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

sample_list=[]

num_sample_list=[]

sample = raw_input('Please enter text to be encoded: \n')

def index_text(text):
    count = 0
    len_text = len(text)
    while count < len_text:
        letter = text[count]
        sample_list.append(letter)
        count += 1

index_text(sample)

def assign_num(letter_list, abc_list):
    count = 0
    for count in range(len(letter_list)):
        for x in range(len(abc_list)):
            if abc_list[x] == letter_list[count]:
                num_sample_list.append(count)
        count += 1

assign_num(abc,sample_list)

print sample_list

print num_sample_list[0]

print num_sample_list[1]

print num_sample_list[2]

print num_sample_list[3]

print num_sample_list
```

**RESULTS**

```
Please enter text to be encoded: 

Sample Message Here

['S', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'M', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'r', 'e']

0

1

5

7

[0, 1, 5, 7, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19]
```

Comment: you define `assign_num(letter_list, abc_list):` but later you run it with arguments in diffferent order `assign_num(abc,sample_list)`. It should be `(sample_list, abc)`

Comment: you can use `abc.index("g")` to get number for char `"g"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead; tweaking according to your final goal.

```py
msg = "Sample Message Here"
a = [ord(char) - 96 for char in msg]
print(a)

[19, 1, 13, 16, 12, 5, -64, 13, 5, 19, 19, 1, 7, 5, -64, 8, 5, 18, 5]
```

To reverse

```py
b = "".join([chr(i + 96) for i in a])
print(b)

"Sample Message Here"
```

Comment: How can I reverse this to get the character from the integer?

Comment: Probably better to explicitly use a dictionary instead of `ord()` so that characters outside the acceptable domain aren't given bogus values.